# Punctuation Query Regarding a Comma and a Parenthesis

Tags: punctuation

*On 24th January 2014 at about 10:25pm, I, John Doe (Loss Prevention Manager for the XYZ Corporation), interviewed and obtained an oral and a written confession from Patricia Schmoe (Cashier at XYZ Stores) in which she admitted to stealing $3,000 cash from the customer service desk.*

1. Should I place a comma – as I've done – after the ending parenthesis after the word "corporation"?
2. Do we cap a title as generic as "Cashier" in the parentheses?
3. Would you use "oral" or "verbal" confession?
4. Do I need any commas inserted in "On 24th January 2014 at about 10:25pm"?

Thank you.

Comment: Items in brackets are irrelevant (the rule simply being you must be able to completely remove the brackets and everything within them, and leave valid punctuation). (Also probably remove a leading space, obviously!) The "cashier" isn't a proper noun - only Victorians and earlier writers would capitalise. "Verbal" is probably better than "oral", but it's your choice. Same with your date (but I'd say ***the** 24th **of*** and a commas after the century).

Comment: Is this what you meant, FumbleFingers? Leave "Loss Prevention Manager" uppercase, but lowercase "cashier"?  *On the 24th of January 2014, at about 10:25pm, I, John Doe (Loss Prevention Manager for the XYZ Corporation), interviewed and obtained a verbal and a written confession from Patricia Schmoe (cashier at XYZ Stores) in which she admitted to stealing $3,000 cash from the customer service desk.*

Comment: You never asked about that one. There's *slightly* more justification for capitalising there (there can only be *one* loss prevention manager in the company, so it's getting closer to a "proper noun"). But I wouldn't anyway - *especially* not when it's juxtaposed with non-capitalised "cashier". I'm sure many who identify themselves as [Smith, general manager](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22smith+general+manager%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are tempted to "Big Themselves Up", but plenty aren't. Whatever - this is becoming proofreading.

Answer (score 1):

1. As stated by @FumbleFingers, parenthetical comments should be removable. Taking this phrase out the comma should follow the name. An alternative construction would be  "I, John Doe, Loss Prevention Manager for the XYZ Corporation,
2. You capitalize proper nouns, that is ones that are unique, "cashier" probably isn't, "Loss Prevention Manager" probably is.
3. Oral means of the mouth, while it can mean speech, it can also relate to other things e.g. oral hygiene, oral medicine. Verbal is better as it means spoken words.
4. No